# ASP.NET Webforms Gridview Footer

Tags: c#, css, gridview, webforms

In ASP.NET webforms, is there a way to configure the `FooterTemplate` of the `GridView` to allow for overflow in the footer, but to also retain the above columns width like below? As it is now, any footer overflow also stretches the cells above it.

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `gridview_rowcreated()` event.

Just in the event allow rowspan and column with desired column and row

Modify it with your requirement.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        GridView FooterGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow FooterRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell Cell_Footer = new TableCell();
        Cell_Footer.Text =""; // As per your requirement
        Cell_Footer.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        Cell_Footer.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Footer);

        Cell_Footer = new TableCell();
        Cell_Footer.Text = ""; // As per your requirement
        Cell_Footer.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        Cell_Footer.ColumnSpan = 1;
        Cell_Footer.RowSpan = 2;
        FooterRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Footer);

        Cell_Footer = new TableCell();
        Cell_Footer.Text = ""; // as per your requiremnt
        Cell_Footer.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        Cell_Footer.ColumnSpan = 3;
        FooterRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Footer);

        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, FooterRow);

    }
}
```

If want more explanation go through the link
http://codedisplay.com/merge-merging-or-split-spliting-gridview-header-row-or-columns-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I needed but thanks either way, since it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Abbath you can span according to your requirement. just do it in RowCreated() event. and check that rowtype must be a footer. otherwise it will point to actual datarows